# Mern stacks deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, deployment, mern

```html
// this is my index.js pubblished on vercel

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname+'/.env'});
}
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
const userRoute = require("./routes/users");
const postRoute = require("./routes/posts");
const categoryRoute = require("./routes/categories");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
dotenv.config();

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: false,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("MongoDB connected!");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/images")));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, req.body.name);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
app.post("/api/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json("File has been uploaded");
});
//endpoints
app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/posts", postRoute);
app.use("/api/categories", categoryRoute);

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
  res.json({
    "ciao":"io sono il backend",
  });
});

// static files (build of your frontend)
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend', 'build')));
  app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend', 'build', 'index.html'));
  })
}

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
  console.log("Listening at port 5000");
});
```

I created a Mern blog with 2 folders: one client (the front end part) and api (the back end part). I would like to distribute in a free hosting, but I don't want to use Heroku, because after November 22nd it will be paid, How can I do this deployment without Heroku in the server part, can someone clarify my ideas on the procedure to do? do i have to merge the two folders?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to deploy your server in [vercel](https://vercel.com/), and your client side on [netlify](https://www.netlify.com/), that's both are free, and suitable for free MERN Stack deployment. To deploy on vercel and nelify is simple, just connect your github repo project to vercel and netlify, automatically make update on deployment if you're push on your repo github. Don't need to merge two folder.

Comment: ok i did as you suggested and thank you, now i have the back end part on vercel and the front part on netifly. Now what is the second step? do I have to replace the local hosts of the front end?
const PF = 'http: // localhost: 5000 / images /' like this const PF = 'https://blog-green-b.vercel.app/images/' ?? and I also have the MongoDB database .. ??

Comment: i suggest you to replace your backend api based on your vercel link, example like https://yourlink.vercel.app/images, so dont need to use localhost anymore, and i suggest you to use mongodb atlas, tha's very simple

Comment: thanks for the answer aknadif, I replaced all the localhost links, of the front end part which is published on netifly as an example this const PF = "https://blog-green-b2.vercel.app/images/" and I already have a mongoDB database where I worked locally, but it doesn't connect ...